# Ng2-translate - Fallback to default language when file doesn't exist

Tags: angular, ionic2, ng2-translate

I have set up ng2-translate which translates my entire app and I have an `en-GB.json` file which contains all of my translations. The problem I have now is that if the user's device is set to another language (e.g. 'en-US'), I get 404 errors saying that the file `en-US.json` doesn't exist.

I have tried this solution https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate#how-to-handle-missing-translations but it seems that I would have to set up a default value for every single translation which isn't great.

Is there a way to automatically fall back to using the `en-GB.json` file if `en-US.json` (and other language files) doesn't exist?

Thanks for any help.

Edit:

Forgot to mention that I also set a default language like so:

```
Globalization.getPreferredLanguage().then(
    res => {
      language = res.value;
      self.translate.setDefaultLang('en-GB');
      self.translate.use(language);
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep a reference to all languages you support in an array and check if the `language` is inside the array. If it exists, you set the `language`, if not you set your default language.

```
const langs = [
    'en-GB',
    'fr-FR',
    'de-DE'
];

let isSupported = this.langs.find(supportedLanguage => supportedLanguage === language);

if(isSupported) self.language.set(language);
else self.language.set('en-GB')
```

Comment: Ah of course! I was trying to overthink it and use some sort of ng2-translate method but this way is much more simple. Thanks!